# Apache proxy to FTPS

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy, ftps

I have a CentOS 6.4 server with Apache 2.2.15.

I would like to do a proxy to ftps server. Bellow you can find my configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:8001>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/root

RewriteEngine On

SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile "ssl/cert.pem"
ProxyRequests Off

<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / ftp://IP:990/
ProxyPassReverse / ftp://IP:990/

ErrorLog  logs/proxy.error.log
CustomLog logs/proxy.access.log common

</VirtualHost>
```

When I am trying to do a proxy URL:

```
curl -ik http://localhost:8001/
```

I am getting a following response in logs:

```
 [Tue Dec 10 13:17:22 2013] [error] [client IP] proxy: SSL/TLS required on the control channel returned by /
```

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your setup the FTP connection you're setting up from your webserver to the FTP server is plain FTP  (`ftp://`), not FTP over SSL (FTPS) as per  `ProxyPass / ftp://IP:990/`.

Your error message could indicate that the FTPS server in IP:990 is the one declining an unecrypted connection.

As far as I know the Apache mod_proxy_ftp module does not support FTPS.

Answer (score 0):

arent you getting warnings when starting this webserver? Because I think u cant use a vhost definition in combination with wildcards due to the nature of ssl.

You can only use 1 specific ip per SSL (v)host. You need to use a unique ip when defining this in your vhost config.

So that means:

```
Listen 192.168.0.1:8001
NameVirtualHost 192.168.0.1:8001

<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:8001>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Koen, Listen is limited to one IP, I've tried with your suggestion and it doesn't work.

Comment: if use one IP on your sever ofcourse. But SSL only allows for 1 IP per SSL-vhost. If u have more Vhosts on the webserver also using 192.168.0.1 it will indeed not work. Im sure u can use multiple Listen clauses